# Prevent handler overlapping in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am calling a function from `mounted()` but when the elements have been loaded where the same function is also being called, the first called function is being interrupted, hence, it doesn't complete the whole function process.

```
<b-table
      id="my-table"
      :items="getList"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      small
    ></b-table>

mounted() {
    this.getList();
  },

methods: {
   getList(ctx){
     return axios.get(url)
      .then(
      function(response) {
        this.totalRows = response.data.count;
        return response.data.results;
      }.bind(this)
    )
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      return [];
    });
   }
}
```

I need to set the value of the `totalRows` upon page loading, but when I try to debug it, the first call from the mounted is not being completed, thus, the assignment of the `totalRows` value does not take place. But when the second call happens, call from the `b-table`, the assignment of `totalRows` happens. But I need to set the value of the `totalRows` before the second call happens. Is there any way I can execute this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a data value to bind to b-table and initialize it in `getList()`

```
data() {
  return {
    itemList: []
  }
},
methods: {
   getList() {
     return axios.get(url)
      .then(
      function(response) {
        this.totalRows = response.data.count;
        this.itemList = response.data;
      }
    )
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
   }
},
mounted() {
   this.getList();
}


<b-table
      id="my-table"
      :items="itemList"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      small
    ></b-table>
```